# iPhone Landscape Mode returns incorrect view sizes

Tags: iphone, orientation, landscape

Getting a view's bounds rect while in Landscape Mode returns the wrong sizes:

(I know there's been a lot of posts on Landscape mode, but nothing on this problem.)

Starting from a new UIView Template Project, I'm adding a single UIView to the ViewController in Interface Builder (in Landscape Mode) and setting the view size to width=400, height=200;
However when I add a breakpoint in the ViewController
Code:
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 CGRect viewRect = [testView bounds];
}
the sizes are w=220, h=380!
(Even though the view clearly is correct on the screen)

In myViewController.m I've set:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); // home button on right
}
```

In myAppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
 application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;  //home on right
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and in the info.plist I've set: Initial interface orientation = Landscape (right home button)

I'm *not* trying to rotate the view with the iPhone, it is meant to be fixed in Landscape only.

Is there a workaround for this? I need to create some CALayers dependent on the correct view size.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a status-bar-related issue.  That said I don't have a good solution for you.

In addition to looking at the frame, you can look at the bounds.  Sometimes this gives better info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It turns out I had 'Autosize subviews' on the main view controller.Sounds obvious, but since no resizing was taking place, I don't know why this should make a difference, but it's cured it.